# php substr internal behaviour tiny optimization

Tags: php, substr

Is the condition block in the following function already taken care of by php's substr internal ?
I downloaded php source code, but I don't know how to interpret it:

```
function myFunction ($line, $pos){

    // do I really need to do that or will php do it for me ?
    if (0 === $pos) {
        $sub = $line;
    }
    else {
        $sub = substr($line, $pos);
    }                

}
```

Comment: yes it is superfluous, it starts zero, and if you forgot to, you're missing your `return`